# Can newly created items marked "Never Published"?

Tags: publishing

So the current project on which i am working, does not have workflow set and the client needs a barrier against accidental content publish.
Now, if I mark "Never Publish" on the standard value of the templates, All the items will be deleted from the web database.

Is there a way to set all the items created henceforth to never publish ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom hander to `item:created` event and set the value of `Never Publish` to true:

```
public void OnItemCreated(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var createdArgs = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as ItemCreatedEventArgs;

    Assert.IsNotNull(createdArgs, "args");
    if (createdArgs != null)
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(createdArgs.Item, "item");
        if (createdArgs.Item != null)
        {
            Item item = createdArgs.Item;
            item.Editing.BeginEdit();
            item.Publishing.NeverPublish = true;
            item.Editing.EndEdit();
         }
    }
}
```

and register it via patch file:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <events>
      <event name="item:created">
        <handler type="My.Assembly.Namespace.ClassName, My.Assembly" method="OnItemCreated" />
      </event>
    </events>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks @Marek Musielak sometimes the solution is right in front of you but you are too consumed with a specific set of solutions

Answer (score 2):

If you want a code-less approach, just create a Branch Template based on your item template, and set the publishing restrictions on the default item of the branch.

[image]

And

[image]